# Racket - Separate Even and Odd Numbers?

Tags: list, racket, sublist

I'm trying to build a function in Racket/Scheme, where you are given a list of integers, and then it has to sort them into two sublists, one for even numbers, and one for odd numbers.  I'm very new to racket, and I have some of the basics down with manipulating lists, but I can't seen to figure out how to define two sublists and put numbers in each one.

This is what I have so far:

```
    (define (segregate lst)
      (if (empty? lst)
          '()
          (if (even? (car a lst))
              (append (car alst) (segregate (cdr alst))))
```

And from there I'm stuck. So with that if condition, even numbers will be sorted into one list.  But I need the odd numbers too.  The else statement in this condition will give you those odd numbers, but I have no idea how to get them into a separate list.

This is the first time I've actually asked a question  on this site, because my professor is not in his office for some reason.

Comment: This code won't run at the moment.  `car` expects exactly one argument, but you've got `(car a lst)`.  You've also got `(car alst)` and `(cdr alst)`, but no variable `alst`.

Comment: I improved the formatting, now it will be clearer?

Answer (score 1):

So, your function needs to return two lists, right? Your base case needs to return two empty lists, and then in your recursive cases, you fill in the relevant one depending. Here's some skeletal code (fill in the `<???>`):

```
(define (odds-and-evens lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      (values '() '())
      (let-values (((odds evens) (odds-and-evens (cdr lst))))
        (cond ((odd? (car lst)) (values (cons <???> <???>) <???>))
              ((even? (car lst)) (values <???> (cons <???> <???>)))
              (else (values odds evens))))))
```

Comment: Yes, and thanks a lot.  Wasn't aware of the let-values function until now.

Answer (score 1):

Chris' `let-values`-version is spicy, but I would have written it like this to make it tail recursive:

```scm
(define (split left? lst)
  (let loop ((lst lst) (a '()) (b '()))
    (if (null? lst)
        ;; you don't need to use values. `cons` or `list` are sometimes preferred
        (values (reverse a) (reverse b)) 
        (let ((e (car lst)))
          (if (left? e)
              (loop (cdr <???>) (cons <???> <???>) <???>)
              (loop (cdr <???>) <???>  (cons <???> <???>)))))))

(split odd? '(1 2 3 4 ...)) 
; ==> 
; (1 3 ...)
; (2 4 ...)
```

Even though it traverses both lists twice (one to do the separation and one to do the reverse) it's still many times faster and IMO simpler to follow.

If you don't care about the order you just skip the `reverse` step and it will be even faster.

Answer (score 1):

Above codes are confunsing as hell. Racket is a very simple language and it's intended to understand what the code is doing while you're reading it. You can use tail recursion for this problem.

You analyze the first element of A, put it where it should and then call the function again until A is empty.

```
(define segregate
  (lambda (A o e) ;A is the list of integers, o is the list of odds and e is for evens.
      (cond ((empty? A) (list o e))
            ((even? (car A)) (segregate (cdr A) o (append e (car A)))
            (else (segregate (cdr A) (append o (car A)) e)))))
```

Comment: Thanks. Apparently newbies can't answer their own questions, but I think I found a solution, by creating an intermediate function that extracts lists based on any boolean function, and then I just create a list with two sublists that call the function for even and odd.

Comment: That's actually a great approach. You are augmenting the abstraction of the code. Good work.

Comment: Your version is extremely inefficient. Cons-based lists are meant to be built right-to-left, using `cons` (which is an O(1) operation). Trying to build it left-to-right using `append` (which is O(n) for each call) is the wrong way to go. There are two ways to do this: you can use a left-fold and then reverse the result, which is what Sylwester's solution is. Or you can use a right-fold, which is what my solution is.

Comment: Most CS courses try to teach students recursive algorithm using right-folding techniques, which is why my solution preferred that. I, too, used to prefer left-folding for everything, but I have come to learn that right-folding is right (har har) for some situations, such as if you have to reverse the result of the left-fold.

Comment: Yes, tail recursion has advantages _if are no other costs_. In your case, `append` adds a huge cost that negates any advantage tail recursion might bring. Even the `reverse` in Sylwester's solution adds a cost, but it's a one-time cost, and nowhere as bad as calling `append` in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Using built-in `partition`:

```
(define (segregate lst)
  (let-values ([(e o) (partition even? lst)])
    (list e o)))
```

Comment: No, my solution is the `partition` directly, without the `let-values` or transformation to list. ;-) Besides, if you want to transform to list, it's probably more efficient to use `call-with-values` directly: `(call-with-values (lambda () (partition even? lst)) list)`

Comment: Sorry, I only scanned your code when I wrote the answer. You're right. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative would be to use foldr

```
(define (odd-even xs)
  (foldr (lambda (x b)
           (if (odd? x)
               (list (cons x (first b)) (second b))
               (list (first b) (cons x (second b))))) '(()()) xs))

racket@> (odd-even '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7))
'((1 3 5 7) (2 4 6))
```